# Docker Volumes on WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-volume, wsl-2

When I try running a container with a volume that I created on WSL2, it fails to start.
Creating the volume and container with the exact same syntax on a full Ubuntu machine works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```sh
docker volume create ubu-vol
```

> ubu-vol

```
docker run -it -d -v ubu-vol --name ubu-dev ubuntu /bin/bash
```

> 87ee4245f4022d1cf26da32fd701d768d449f679b4441b5bf734d834d9ccf190
> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:ubu-vol Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/volumes/123784ee61e4bc2a77f98e6574ae6c71c4cc7fa6f7e109ac55f8f115df07eba5/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination ubu-vol not absolute: unknown.

Running the container without specifying the volume works fine in WSL2.

```
docker run -it -d --name ubu-dev ubuntu /bin/bash
```

The container starts, and I can attach to it just fine.

I've also tried being more specific with the volume's path (since the error said it needed to be absolute), but I get the same result.

```sh
docker volume create \
    --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt device=:/mnt/d/docker-vol \
    ubu-vol
```

Perhaps it means something different by "absolute path?"
I'd appreciate any insight that you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `--volume/-v` syntax [doesn't look right](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag).  You aren't specifying the path where it should be mounted *inside* the container.

Try:

```
docker run -it -d -v "ubu-vol:/mnt/docker-ubu-vol" --name ubu-dev ubuntu /bin/bash
```

But also consider that Docker recommends using the newer `--mount` option:

```
docker run -it -d --mount "type=volume,src=ubu-vol,dst=/mnt/docker-ubu-vol" --name ubu-dev ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had thought that I was specifying where the volume would live on the host, not the container.